# What does the High Yield weapon quality mean?

Tags: weapons, star-trek-adventures, starship-combat, modiphius-2d20

In the Core Rulebook, several torpedo-type weapons reference the High Yield quality, but this isn't listed in the Qualities on p179. What does High Yield mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're looking for is in the starship rules on p232 of the core rules.

> **High-Yield**: The weapon inflicts massive damage to enemy vessels; if the Attack inflicts one or more Breaches to a system, it inflicts one additional Breach.

What you've found on p179 is just for personal weapons.

Comment: ah thanks. p179 was all that came up when i searched for "qualities"